# Is it possible to alter the order of "kind" sorting?

Tags: finder, mojave, sort

Mojave:

In **list view**, the Finder sorts `Kind` by...

- **Descending** - Folders/Aliases/Other/Documents/images
- **Ascending** - Aliases/Folders/Images/Documents/Other

`Keep Folders on top` is **not** ticked/in use. Yet, folders are **always** on top, whether you want it that way or not. This merely appears to be the default order `Kind` uses.

**Is it possible to change this order?**

Something like Documents/Folders/Aliases/Images/Other

---

Sort By, not Group By..

Group By appears to sort `Kind` as Folder/Aliases/Documents/Images/Other, with no real change based upon asc/dsc except that the Folders/Aliases switch places if asc/dsc is toggled. Other categories don't move.

Comment: It is Folder and Folder Aliases which are at the top.  File Aliases are sorted with files in the expected alphabetical order of Kind.  I know this doesn't solve the problem - just corrects what you are seeing.

Comment: Agreed, @Gilby -- Aliases *could* sort of be seen as "special folders", which is why I assume they are also always on top.